# datastax node.js driver for graph(using gremlin queries), How can I fetch large results set?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-node-driver

Im using datastax node.js driver for dse graph.

According to http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/latest/features/paging/

It works only for Cassandra and DSE, but I would like to do the same for DSE Graph using gremlin queries : fetch and paging results. I would like to know the total records of results too. (without performance issues)

Comment: DSE Graph does not support protocol-level paging yet, so it's not possible to use the DSE drivers to perform paging. You should use gremlin `range()` method instead.